# Vue2 + composition API - dynamic template refs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

I am using Quasar (quasar.dev) with Vue2 + Composition API and am trying to access DOM elements with dynamically generated 'v-bind:ref' properties, following this page of the Vue3 docs:

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for

This is a codesandbox simplified representation of the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-pine-90qgd?file=/src/components/MyOuterComponent.ts

My component template (MyOuterComponent.vue):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <my-component
      v-for="(item, i) in list"
      v-bind:ref="
        (el) => {
          if (el) divs[i] = el
        }
      "
      v-bind:key="i"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </my-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script src='./MyOuterComponent.ts' />
```

and my script for that component:

```js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'
import TMyComponent from './MyComponent'
import {
  defineComponent,
  onMounted,
  ref,
  reactive,
  onBeforeUpdate
} from '@vue/composition-api'
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyOuterComponent',
  components: { MyComponent },
  props: {},
  setup(props, context) {
    const list = reactive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    const divs = ref<InstanceType<typeof TMyComponent>[]>([])

    // make sure to reset the refs before each update
    onBeforeUpdate(() => {
      divs.value = []
    })

    onMounted(() => {
      context.root.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('THE COMPONENTs', divs, context.root.$refs)
        divs.value.forEach((div) => {
          console.log('My Div Ref: ', div)
        })
      })
    })
    return {
      list,
      divs
    }
  }
})
```

As seen in the docs I am expecting `divs` to be populated with the template refs for my dynamically generated components, which is what this line in my template should do:

```
v-bind:ref="(el) => { if (el) divs[i] = el }"
```

`divs` remains empty even when logged after nextTick. I expect to see 5 items referencing DOM elements in there.

If I change the template to:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <my-component
      v-for="(item, i) in list"
      v-bind:ref="item"
      v-bind:key="i"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </my-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script src='./MyOuterComponent.ts' />
```

I see the refs in `context.refs` but am told this property will be removed in Vue3 ;-(

Can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You can now do this in Vue 2.7

Answer (score 3):

It looks that vue-composition-api (vue2) doesn't support the :ref syntax. Take a look at https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api#limitations

A warning should be very helpful there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, wish I had known this earlier before spending hours trying to get it to work ;(

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to import ref:

```
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api"
```

A simple way is to add a ref to the list. You can reference the required `ref` using the list index.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <my-component
      ref="mycomponentRef"
      v-for="(item, index) in list"
      v-bind:key="index"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </my-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export defineComponent({
  setup() {
    // this is an array, [ref0, ref1, ...]
    const mycomponentRef = ref()

    return { mycomponentRef }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not supported as of now, you can still get to the old $refs as a workaround.  This is not in Vue3, but will you by until it is implemented.

```html
  <div v-for='i of 10' :key='i' ref='myRefs' />
```

```js
setup(props, {refs}){
  // Workaround until Vue2 Composition API supports dynamic template refs.
  onMounted(()=>{
     myRefs = refs.myRefs // array of 10 refs
  })
}
```

Comment: {refs} does not exist in the setup context object (Vue 2.7). The context contains only the following keys: attrs, emit, expose, listeners, slots

Comment: ```import { getCurrentInstance } from "vue"; // 2.7

getCurrentInstance().proxy.$refs;
```

Comment: Looks like function refs are merged in Vue 2.7 now.

Comment: @wobsoriano where did you read that? I can't seem to get them working still?

Comment: are you using the plugin @LeeR? It's built-in with v2.7 and aligned with Vue 3 features.

Comment: @wobsoriano, I actually got it going in the end. Was just some bad coding on my behalf by not returning the ref variable (wasn't using the setup script at this time)